# In WinRT how to create an application that is always visible?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, taskbar, always-on-top

With windows 8, is it possible to create an application that is always visible?  For instance, in previous versions of windows, there is the task bar with quick launch icons.  Can I create something similar to the quick launch icons that are always on the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to a Windows 8 Store app then the answer is no.  You can have a live tile and toast notifications that provides updates to the user which may cause the user to launch your application.

A good article to read to understand how your Windows Store apps will run on Windows 8 go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) to learn about Application lifecycle (Windows Store apps).  This will explain the App execution state.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in the RT version, but the same is possible in the desktop version. If you have a desktop app, you can pin it to the taskbar. But any Window store app cannot be pinned to the taskbar. What you can do instead is move the app to the beginning of your Home screen, so anytime you click the Windows button your app will be visible right in front.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean always visible in the Star Menu screen? If so, you can add tile updating functionality to your application. As long as the user has the application pinned to the Start Menu, he would see the updates. Check the link below for an introductory tutorial.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/16/creating-a-great-tile-experience-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"Quick Launch" has a very specific meaning, which you may or may not have been referring to in your question.

Below is the Quick Launch bar in Windows 8 - essentially a toolbar pointing to a location in your `%AppData%` directory.  Prior to Windows 7 it was available by default, but the ability to now pin items directly to the taskbar rather supersedes it.  [Here's how you can restore Quick Launch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975784) if you really want to :)

[image: Quick Launch in Windows 8]

It's, of course, available only in the Desktop mode and not on the Modern UI, where pinning a tile is the best you can hope for, and it's all up to the user to pin it AND to determine where it shows up on their Start Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Another option worth mentioning (although more like system tray than quick launch) is [lock screen presence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779720.aspx). If the user chooses so and your app supports that, he can add it to his lock screen:

- either as a a badge (up to 7 apps)
- or as a tile notification (single app only)

This is not a way for the user to quickly start your app (other answers have already covered these options) but a way to stay visible and keep your user informed.